# Rewrite query string url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url : **example.com/view/?=content**

and i want : **example.com/view/content**

I tried these codes but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/view/(.*)$ /view/?url=$1 [L]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /view/?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

No initial `/` in `RewriteRule` left expression in `.htaccess`

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash from your rewrite pattern :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /view/?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```